# Get earliest object by field in django

Tags: django, performance, model

I have `date_updated` field in my model. I want to get object whose `date_updated` time is oldest or is null/blank 
How can I do this most efficient way?

```
class Product(models.Model):
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
```

Comment: Can you share the other models of your object ?

Comment: Do you mean, code of the model?

Comment: Yes,Please share the fields of your particular model

Comment: Please check updated post

Comment: If date_updated is `None`,what would be the next parameter you would like to filter ?

Comment: Do you want "NULL > old > new" order or "old > new > NULL" order?

Comment: This field's purpose is only to check how recently field was updated and if it is older than others, or data is not set it should be updated. I guess it should be null > old > new

Comment: If you set `date_updated` to `auto_now_add=True` then this would be super easy. And you could tell which ones had NOT been updated because `date_updated == date_created` would be `True`.

Comment: Is `date_created` some default field? What if I update some items and then add some new and run update again. New Items will have most recent `date_updated` date with no data in other fields which get updated with update.

Comment: I'm suggesting you add a field called `date_created`. Then you will always know when and how changes occurred. You asked for the most efficient way, and I believe this is it.

Comment: I already have `date_added` field in my model with `auto_now_add` set to True. Can you please give a snippet how can I select needed object this way?

Comment: OK, `date_updated` has `auto_now=True` (not `auto_now_add`, sorry). So you can easily get the most recently updated object using an `F` object:   `Product.objects.all().exclude(date_added=F('date_updated')).order_by('-date_updated').last()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want in priority the elements that are `None`, you can use the [queryset method `.latest([field])`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#latest):

```
YourModel.objects.latest('date_updated')
```

It will return the most recent date, or the first one (with the default ordering set in your Meta model) if at least one is null.

Comment: Looks like this is appropriate way to do such kind of queries, isn't it?

Comment: In my case it would be `earliest` method.

Answer (score 1):

`oldest_date = YourModel.objects.all().order_by("-date_updated")[0`]

However, I am not sure how this will work with Null values. To make sure you can treat them separately:

```
oldest_date = YourModel.objects.exclude(date_updated=None).order_by("-date_updated")[0]

never_updated = YourModel.objects.filter(date_updated=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use `Foo.objects.all().order_by('-date_updated').last()` to get the oldest one. But the null/blank option presents a problem, since it will potentially return multiple objects, in no particular order. I guess you could just pick one.

If you're trying to get the oldest one, including those that have never been updated, you could set `date_update` to `NOW()` when you create the object (that's what I do).